# Does an electron of n side recombines only with holes of p side or also get recombined at the n side itself?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, solid-state-physics, electronics

Suppose there is an electron at the n side.Does the electron have to travel until the p side to get recombined or is it like an electron travels some distance along n side gets recombined ,then another electron pops up moves a small distance then recombines again and this process repeats until it reaches hole in the n side.

Or is it like the electron can move until it reaches the hole in p side.

Also if there is a voltage source why do these electrons in conduction band lose energy to fall into the hole in the diode.

Comment: Carrier equilibrium in a semiconductor is a dynamic equilibrium - e-h pairs are being generated and recombining all the time. Just where a carrier recombines, and the carrier lifetimes, depends on what all is happening in the device.